# Fastest way to import new records from one database to another?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

Using EF, I need to pull records from one database, do some initialization and mapping, and insert the records into another DB. I need to only so this for records that have not already been imported. My model on the secondary DB looks like:

```
public class Loan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // this is the id of this loan's record from the original DB
    public int OriginalDbId { get; set; }

    // the loan's last date of attendance
    public DateTime LDA { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Approach 1:

I added a model called ImportHistory that just saved the time of the last import. I used this date to pull loans where the LDA was greater than the last time of import. The problem is that a user can edit the LDA of a loan causing some loans to be missed and vise verse. For example, if a loan was created after the last import, but edited so that the LDA is before the last import, the new loan would not be imported.

Approach 2:

I retrieved all OriginalDbIds from the secondary DB. And then pulled all records where the Id was not contained in the collection of OriginalDbIds. Note that there's a bit more selection criteria contained in the query.

```
var allIds = _2ndDbLoanRepo.Query()
    .Select(m => m.OriginalDbId)
    .ToList();
var newRecords = _1stDbLoanRepo.Query()
    .Where(other criteria ...)
    .Where(m => !allIds.Contains(m.Id))
    .ToList();
```

This approach will end up being way to slow when there's 100k+ records already found. It's already throwing an EntityCommandExecutionException, with the message "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding", when there's only 10k records.

So what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Fastest way would be if data never leaves the DB server. The server process updates a log table and front end updates out of that log table

Comment: @T.S. The 2 databases live on different servers. And there's some initializing/attaching/mapping stuff I need to do in code in between the two databases.

Comment: Servers can be linked and mapping can be saved as metadata to be used by server process. Have you thought of doing it export/import style? Export to text file, import from text file. This is how Database does it, why your program should be different?

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it that way. I know it's bad but EF has kept me from digging to deep into sql or dms in general. Exporting would still need to know which records have already been exported. I don't have access to edit the original db either. Do you have anything to guide me to doing it this way? How will the original db know which records to export?

Comment: With a linked server you just a select x from sourceTable where not exists (select 1 from targetTable where targetTable.id = sourceTable.id).  You use 4 part names for the tables.

Comment: @Blam Linked Server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: Ahhh - this should work. Make an answer @T.S. and I'll accept after setting up and testing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @T.S. I know what a linked server is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way would be if data never leaves the DB server. The server process updates a log table and front end updates out of that log table – T.S. yesterday

1 - Servers can be linked and mapping can be saved as metadata to be used by server process.

2 - Have you thought of doing it export/import style? Export to text file, import from text file. This is how Database does it, why your program should be different?